# XtraReports v.10.2: VerticalContentSplitting does not affect XRLabel

Tags: devexpress

I have an XtraReport report whose Detail band contains XRLabel controls.
the rightmost XRLabel crosses the right page margin, so it is split by the margin.
I did not like this behavior and changed XtraReport.VerticalContentSplitting to VerticalContentSplitting.Smart. But this did NOT change anything.

What is the reason?

Comment: I believe that DX support guys can help you in this regard.

Comment: You really need to accept some answers

Comment: 'I believe that DX support guys can help you in this regard' - yes, but in complicated cases the stackoverflow.com visitors gave me good avdices about the DX, I remember

Answer (score 0):

Are your labels part of an `XRTable`?  There is an [outstanding issue](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S30683.aspx) with the `VerticalContentSplitting` setting.  Otherwise, you could just manually move or resize the overlapping `XRLabel` control.

As mentioned in the comments, you should ask in the DevExpress forums - that's where the guys who actually build their tools hang out.  You can upload an example of your problem and they'll fix it for you.

Comment: "Are your labels part of an XRTable" - no they do not. This is why I consider this situation as problem